# Cannot read NFC tag over Sceneform ux ArFragment

Tags: android, nfc, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to read an NFC tag over a sceneform ux ArFragment. The idea is that I wish to have a 3D model appear, and change that model based on what NFC tag was scanned (like an Amiibo). Using the same code I was able to read NFC tags through another activity, but not the same activity where the ArFragment is.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nfcManager = new NFCManager(this);
    nfcManager.onActivityCreate();
    // use code to read from tag
    nfcManager.setOnTagReadListener(new NFCManager.TagReadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTagRead(String tagRead) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "tag read:" + tagRead, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            buildCharacterModel(tagRead);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    nfcManager.readTag(intent);
}
```